# send bokeh plot to websocket in tornado

Tags: python, tornado, bokeh

I have a problem with bokeh and Tornado.

I am using Tornado as my webserver (I cannot use the bokeh embedded server). 
One of my pages creates a websocket connection and is supposed to receive dynamically generated bokeh graphs from the server.

I generate the graph with the following code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components
plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

script, div = components(plot)
```

then I send the script and div to the listening websocket (this is done in my tornado websocket handler):

```
write_message(div+script)
```

The client has a div with id = 'wsResponse' in which I want to insert the result:

```
document.getElementById("wsResponse").innerHTML = data;
```

Where data is the previously generated div and script, sent to the websocket.

The problem is that nothing is rendered, as the script is indeed javascript code and cannot be inserted by the innerHTML directive.

Any workaround please?

Comment: `components` accepts a `wrap_script` param that can be set to `False`: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html#bokeh.embed.components Doing so will return the raw JS which you could potentially `eval` directly. You'd have to find a way to split the div from the js code, or send them separately.

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml